# how to derive the steps of principal component analysis?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to understand the theoretical reasoning behind the method, but I can't understand a particular step in the middle of this [page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section5/pmc551.htm).

"The constraint on the numbers in $v_1$ is that the sum of the squares of the coefficients equals $1$. Expressed mathematically, we wish to maximize
$$\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^NY_{1i}^2$$

where
$$y_{1i}=v_1'z_i,$$

and $$v_1'v_1=1$$

(this is called "normalizing" $v_1$).
Computation of first principal component from $R$ and $v_1$. Substituting the middle equation in the first yields

$$\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^NY_{1i}^2=v_1'Rv_1."$$

I don't understand how $R$ suddenly appeared in this equation. The right hand side "$v_1' R v_1$" seems to have appeared out of nowhere.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N Y_{1i}^2 &= \frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N (v_1'z_i)(z_i'v_1)\\
&=v_1'\left(\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N z_iz_i' \right) v_1 \\
&= v_1'Rv_1
\end{align}

where $R=\frac1N \sum_{i=1}^N z_iz_i'.$

Comment: umm, question. why can you alter the order of the two variables when you square them? in v1'zi * zi'v1

Comment: To make it into a form that is desirable to us.

Comment: sorry I can't really understand.

am I confused about what the (') mark means? i thought maybe that it was referring to a matrix transpose since derivative doesn't make sense here

Comment: we have $(v_1'z_i)=(z_i'v_1)$ since they are scalar. yes ' means transpose.

Comment: ah ok then it makes sense if they are scalars..

is R = 1/N sum zi * zi' the definition of correlation?

or is there some reason why that is the case?

Comment: note that $z$ is standardized, hence yes, that would be the definition.

Comment: k thanks for the help. Would never figure any of this out on my own.

Comment: it takes time to pick up the maths.